# I want to make v-card transparent, but it doesn't work right

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I want that v-card be transparent, but what is inside it should not be transparent. How can I make it with CSS?

card.vue

```
    <v-card class="cardColor">
      <v-card-text>
        TEXT
      </v-card-text>
      <v-card-actions>
        <v-btn color="primary" @click="foo">Button</v-btn>
      </v-card-actions>
    </v-card>
```

common.css

```
    .cardColor {
       background-color: white!important;
       border-color: transparent!important;
       opacity: 0.65;
     }
```

I tried to write this, but it doesn't work.

```
    .cardColor {
       color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
     }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow _ I don't know VueJS but if you want the background to be transparent it looks as though you have the elements in your CSS the wrong way round _ `background-color: white !important;` should be transparent and presumably `border-color: transparent !important;` should be white

Comment: Changing a parent element's opacity will always effect *all of its descendants*. There is no way to circumvent that, functionally, so what you're describing isn't possible. Consider providing an explanation of the *goal* as opposed to your attempted solution; perhaps a screenshot or mockup of the desired effect. You can likely achieve it using a workaround.

Comment: You need to override the Vuetify css definitions on `v-card` (background, shadow, etc) with your own. So `background: transparent;` and `box-shadow: initial` etc. Don't add opacity or it will affect everything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I put a transparent to the card background and remove the opacity, this is what you need?

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
})
setTimeout(()=>console.clear(), 100)
```

```css
#app {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(226,226,226,1) 0%, rgba(254,254,254,1) 100%);
}
.cardColor {
   background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) !important;
   border-color: white !important;
 }
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@3.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>

 <div id="app">
    <v-app>
      <v-content>
        <v-container>
          <v-card class="cardColor">
            <v-card-text>
              TEXT
            </v-card-text>
            <v-card-actions>
              <v-btn color="primary" @click="foo">Button</v-btn>
            </v-card-actions>
          </v-card>
        </v-container>
      </v-content>
    </v-app>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, yes I wanted transparent for card, but not 100% transparent, I think about **0.8 - 0.9** transparent.

Comment: @Maks I edited the snippet, only change the background color transparency to a rgba value with your desired value, I hope this can help you

Answer (score 6):

you can use color property with outlined

```
<v-card outlined color="transparent">
   ...
</v-card>
```

Answer (score 2):

if you want a card with transparent background, you can choose one of these options:

1. add *flat* property to your v-card component, and set color="transparent".

   ```
   <v-card flat color="transparent">
     ...
   </v-card>
   ```
2. add *flat* prop to your v-card and add the following style:

   ```
   <v-card flat style="background-color: transparent;">
      ...
   </v-card>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

In CSS, we can achieve it by the following style:

```
.cardColor 
{ 
    z-index: 1; 
    position: relative; 
    width: 100%; 
    float: left; 
}

.cardColor:before 
{ 
    position: absolute; 
    content: ""; 
    display: block; 
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%; 
    background: #fff; 
    opacity: 0.35; 
    top: 0; 
    left: 0; 
    z-index: -1; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In "vuetify": "^3.4.3" updated the props

```
<v-card variant="outlined" color="transparent">
   ...
</v-card>
```